# s7 edge in download mode

Tags: updates, downloading, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I just got the Samsung Galaxy s7 Edge like 2 weeks ago. Right now as I am packing up to school and I charge my phone plus turn it on I get in this "Download Mode". It has been stuck in this mode for about an hour. Did something happen to my phone or is it an android 7.0 nougat update? This is what it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try holding the power button for like 5 to 10 seconds to force a reboot. There is no indicator showing any progress of an update so I think you accidently booted into the recovery mode (holding volume down +  power button while booting up).

Comment: @benjamin oh. I thought it was an update :(